# How to make second or more firestore collection based on the same logged in user flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a new collection data that based on the same user that logged in or the same document uid.

this is the firestore
[image: Example firestore]

as you can see the uid based on currently logged in user.

I have a method to insert it to database like this but if i fill the dropdowns and submit the data it just update it not increase or multiply to second, third or more.

```
 Future CreateEducation(MyEducation educationsss) async {
    String date1 = selectedMonthStart! + " " + selectedYearStart.toString();
    print(date1);
    // DateFormat datestart = DateFormat.yMMMM(date1);
    // print(datestart);
    String date2 = selectedMonthEnd! + " " + selectedYearEnd.toString();
    print(date2);
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final docEducation = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("education")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

    final userEducation = MyEducation(
      uid: uid,
      universityName: collegeAheadController.text,
      universityImage: imageuniversitycollege,
      major: SelectedMajor.toString(),
      degree: SelectedDegree.toString(),
      dateEnd: date1,
      dateStart: date2,
    );
    final json = userEducation.toJson();

    await docEducation.set(json);
  }
```

i want to create multiple of this
[[image: only 1 per docs1]

can't it be done with the same docs id? mayble alternative using uid inside the collection?

Comment: so basically you want every data submit you make, it should create a new document in that collection ?

Comment: ohh, now I reviewed again your issue, consider creating a sub collection inside the uid document, like this FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("education").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).collection('subCollection')

Comment: ohhhh then everytime user create new education they create new sub collections? @Gwhyyy

Comment: yes, and every user will have his own sub collection

Comment: can they have multiple sub collections?

Comment: yes, they can go to 100 sub collection for each document, check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields

Answer (score 1):

you should go for subcollections something like as follows :

```
     final docEducation = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("education")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection("educations")
        .doc();
```